# Linking a transparent DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a background image running in my normal HTML website. I have added the  2 LOGOS of another website in my background Image. How do i create a transparent DIV and LINK The portion only with the logo to my website More like a hotspot when i click on the logo it should open in a new tab and display the webpage??? AnyHelp will be appreciated! :)

This is the CSS for the Box,

```
#logobox1 {
    width: 114px;
    height: 28px;
    Left: 1850;
    top: 43;    
}
#logobox2 {
    width: 92px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 1857;
    top: 40;
}
```

Comment: Please show the HTML as well. Also creating a JSFiddle would be great too.

Comment: ALright! Give me a minute

Comment: @MitulP91 Check it out The black spots are where i want the logo .... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You linked it wrong. Also, look at hungerstar's resposne below. Seems like that is something similar to what you want.

Comment: Sorry!! http://jsfiddle.net/afshandc/ReYq2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is an anchor tag `<a>` and not a div.

We use absolute positioning, `position: absolute;`, on the anchor tag.  In order for this to work it's containing element should use relative positioning, `position: relative;`.  Then we set the anchor tags display to block, `display: block;`, so it will accept the dimensions we give it.  Which will of course be the dimensions of your image.

Other than that it's a matter of moving it from the top and left of the containing element until it is in the correct position.

http://jsfiddle.net/UHTPx/1/

*HTML*

```html
<div class="container">
    <a class="hitbox" href="google.com" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

I added borders to each element for illustrative purposes.

*CSS*

```css
.container {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/150/75/abstract/') no-repeat center center;
    border: 1px dashed #DEDEDE;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
.hitbox {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    height: 75px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    margin-top: -37.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
}
```